# Why do I have a segmentation fault when starting my C++ program with gdb?

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, segmentation-fault, g++

I have a g++ project and would like to debug it using gdb. Opening gdb with the program as an argument produces the following output:

```
Reading symbols from <my_app_name>...Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Compilation flags

```
-c -Wall -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -g
```

Link flags

```
-lssl -lcrypto -pthread -luuid -rdynamic
```

My executable file size is 2,141,712 with debug informations present
The 'top command' reveals 3,417,168 free memory.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3.1) 7.7
```

I have had limited experience with gdb in the past, and I am meaning to use gdb with this project, unfortunately, since gdb segmentation fault when started with my executable, the debugging experience will be difficult. Can someone please help?

I also asked this question [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471173/why-is-gdb-progfile-producing-a-segmentation-fault?noredirect=1#comment623666_471173) but my question got closed there, as it is more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

At first look:

Your compilation flags seem to be missing a leading dash:

```
-c std=c++11 -g
```

Should probably be: (`add leading dash in front of std=c++11`)

```
-c -std=c++11 -g
```

Your link flags:

```
-lssl -lcrypto -pthread -luuid -std=c++11-rdynamic
```

should probably be: (`add space between -std=c++11 and -rdynamic`)

```
-lssl -lcrypto -pthread -luuid -std=c++11 -rdynamic
```

Please note that you don't need the `-std=c++11` option twice (config & link flags).

Give it another try with the updated flags.

Comment: Sorry @iomix, I entered a typo when I recopied my CXXFLGS. I have edited the original question with the proper flags. I really did have the leading - before -std=c++11. I also removed the -std=c++11 from the link flags, thanks for the tip. FYI, after removing the link flag -std=c++11, I still get the segfault loading the project from gdb.